# UML idea for objects with similar characteristics.

Tags: java, design-patterns, uml, use-case

[image]

Events, jobs, self and contact are nothing but DTO objects where each objects can be added, edited and deleted from database. I am not so familiar with use case diagrams so I wanted to know if this is correct or can be improved.

Is there something to be generalised here? add edit and delete methods in implementations are handled by one class. but the call are handled separately for each object. Is this ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use case diagrams are typically used to describe the requirements of the system, **from the point of view of the user**. It is fine that "*Manage Contacts*" and "*Manage Events*" are your use cases, but the use case model should be independent on which classes represent Contacts and Events. (Lower level details are better described in other diagrams)

Second, an *extend* relationship specifies "**how and when the behavior defined in the extending use case can be inserted into the behavior defined in the extended use case**". The extended use case is that ***pointed by the arrow***. Then the arrows should be reversed, because *Add Contact * extends *Manage Contacts*: at some point in the execution of "*Manage Contact*", if some conditions are met (e.g. the user has selected "add") the behavior of "*Add Contact*" is executed.

Indeed, this is a very forced interpretation of extend relationship in order to fit your model. I think that it could be better described by generalizations: "*Manage Contact*" is an abstract use case, that is specialized by "*Add Contact*", "*Edit Contact*" and "*Delete Contact*" (and the same for Events, Jobs, etc).

If you want to model that every "*Add/Edit/Delete*" use case have **something in common** with the other use cases, you might model that as abstract use cases. Then "*Add Contact*" is not only a  specialization of "*Manage Contact*", but also a specialization of "*Add*" (which define the behavior of adding some entity).

[image]

Comment: I am just confused what "manage order" means to each of its child use case and how to write the pre condition and flow of events for such use case

Comment: I think that "*Manage X*" should be an **abstract** use case (i.e. it does not provide a complete behavior, perhaps only a brief description in natural language, and an include relationship with *Login*). The behaviors would be defined for "*Add X*", and specialized by "*Add X*" which factors in the differences between adding an Event and adding a Contact. (Same for "*Edit*" and *Delete*).

You may also make explicit whether the generalization *is covering* (i.e. whether the only use cases that specialize "*Manage X*" are those represented in the diagram).

Comment: what do you mean by "forced interpretation" sir, in you explanation of extend

Comment: If it were an extension, *Manage Contacts* would have to describe when it executes *Add Contact*, *Edit Contact* or *Delete Contact*. **It is not wrong**, but maybe it is saying something that you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, "Manage X" should never be a use case. A use case is a particular functionality of your application, that has a precise purpose from the user point of view. "Manage" is always too vague for a use case.

In fact, "Manage X", here, is clearly a package, and will be named "X management". These packages will allow you to separate parts of your application. And there is no need to group the Add X, Add Y, Add Z, the only thing they have in common is that you will perform an insert in database in the end. Though it would be valid to use inheritance for these, I don't think it is worth it.

So, to my mind, you should have independent use cases grouped in packages.

And one more advice: I wouldn't use the insert relationship with Login. These relationships are correct, of course, but they crowd your diagram, and could very well be implicit. A typical way to make a distinction between use cases that require a login and others is to use two actors, one being an anonymous "User", the other being your "Academic".